# how to conver this sentence to propositional logic

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have the following scenario:

[image]

if someone is killed in any of the rooms there would be bad smell for the rooms horizontally or vertically next to that room and for that room itself for example if a person is killed in dinning room there would be stench in library dinning and conservatory rooms so

I made four rules like this :
b1: sd => BL  or Bd or  Bc  which gives  not Sd or BL or Bd or  Bc

andI made four of these rules

Now I want to say this sentenceaccording to the rules that are made above:

the person is  not in library:
I startedin this way: not BL  =>  Bk or Bd or  Bc  which gives   BL or Bk or Bd or  Bc

but now I am stuck and I can not go any  further. I want to say that sentence at the end according to the b1,b2,b3,b4

Can anyone help?

Comment: If the smell only carries horizontally and diagonally, then the dining room murder would stink up the dining room, library, and kitchen, not the conservatory.  How does the smell know not to go vertically?

Comment: OHHH I changed diagonally to horizontally in the text of question  thanks for mentioning that(smell can not go diagonally)

Comment: Dude, the whole house is gonna stink.

Comment: No if the body is in kitchen dinning room would not stink smell does not goes diagonally